# Windows 10 Bash - Can't install flux - Multiple errors

Tags: bash, windows-10

When I'm trying to install certain programs using `apt-get` on Ubuntu Bash on Windows, some things also try to install `flux`, but it doesn't want to install. There are many errors, but they might be caused by only one. This snippet is from me trying `sudo apt-get install ruby`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Setting up fuse (2.9.4-1ubuntu1) ...
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1655 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
Creating fuse device...
/sbin/MAKEDEV: warning: can't read /proc/devices
mknod: ‘fuse-’: Function not implemented
makedev fuse c 10 229 root root 0660: failed
chmod: cannot access ‘/dev/fuse’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package fuse (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fuse
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Why not just use RubyInstaller ? and install DevKit after that ?

Comment: @niceman I should elaborate, I'm trying to install something that requires ruby, there's a version of it on windows, but the support is much better on linux.

Comment: can you tell what's that "something" ? also i don't think the purpose of bash in windows is to run linux apps but actually to have a more powerful command-line for windows(useful for powerusers,developers :) )

Comment: Ok sorry, don't know why I said 'something' :D I'm installing metasploit, it requires a lot of stuff, and when I run the command to install them, this error occurs. I understand that may not be the point of it, but it's painfully slow on Windows.

Comment: bash on windows != linux on windows as linux is a different kernel with different API :)

Comment: @niceman Yes, but if there's a workaround then it should be possible, right?

Comment: even if there is a way to install the linux version of that app, it won't run as smooth as the windows version, if you find windows version to be slow well the only solution is to get linux :) (by the way don't be sure that the linux version will be faster on linux than the windows version on windows :) )